# Open jQuery dialog on page load, on submit click redirect to same page without dialog loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dialog

On page load I open up a dialog that allows the user to enter information and then click one of two buttons. Each button has an onclick function to redirect to a specific page. One button goes to a different page and this works fine, the window closes and parent redirects to the different page. The other button needs to redirect back to the same page it came from. This makes the dialog display again. Can someone tell me the most common solution for something like this? jQuery cookies, php session?

Comment: How does the dialog display to begin with?  Does it open automatically when the page loads?  If not, are you sure the page is reloading?

Comment: it opens In jquery document load.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is reloading because I am usingwindow.redirect onclick

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use `php sessions` but u can use javascript cookies :) and after user first visit set it and check on every visit either is set not or not, if set it should not display dialog box if not show dialog box.
as

```
 function setcookie()
{
   now = new Date();
   now.setMonth( now.getMonth() + 12 ); 
   te ="chk=1; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";";
   document.cookie = te;
}
 function chkcookie() {
   cooki = document.cookie;
  cookie = cooki.split(';');
cook = cookie[0]
  cookinam = cook.split('=')[1];
   if(cookinam != 1) {
     window.prompt("hi whats ur name","defaultText");
   }


}


<body onload="setcookies(); chkcookie();">
```

here its [bin](http://jsbin.com/onOTeVaj/1/edit?html,js)

and in php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['chk'] = true;  //or 1

if(!isset($_SESSION['chk']))
{
echo "window.prompt(\"hi whats ur name\",\"defaultText\");";
}
?>
```

and sorry i dont know how to use jquery :)